# Error While serializing object to json format using JsonConvert.SerializeObject function

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a method to serialize object to json format. the object contains nested objects and lists. but i face this error :

Error getting value from 'Length' on 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.ArteryFilter'.

```
 Dim serilaize As New JsonSerializerSettings()
        With serilaize
            .PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        End With

        Dim strProgram As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProgramObject, Formatting.Indented, serilaize)
```

Any help please !
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an indication or an example of what the ProgramObject looks like?

Comment: Thanks Peter, the problem cause was something else. i define an object from another class. and its name is similar to aspx page. when i changed the name it worked. appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim ProgramObject = New TestObject()
    ProgramObject.Items = New List(Of String)
    ProgramObject.Items.Add("testitem")

    Dim serialize As New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
    With serialize.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects

    Dim strProgram As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProgramObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, serialize)
    End With
End Sub

End Module
```

TestObject looks like this:

```
Public Class TestObject
    Property Items As List(Of String)
End Class
```